# Prevent users from doing git commit -a

Tags: git

Is there a way to prevent users of a repository from doing `git commit -a` and force them to only do `git add` and them `git commit`?

Comment: Maybe you could setup a git hook to disallow changes on more than n files, but I think as @blue112 said, the best way is to **teach** people and do code reviews. This question is like "How can I disallow people to write bad code".

Answer (score 4):

You couldn't enforce that server side.

Even if you would have a way to prevent that client side, they'll just have to `git add -u` and there's done.

You can try to teach them good practice, or impose code review for every commit pushed, so you can verify that only good file belong to the commit.

Comment: I found that in this specific case people have an easier time ignoring something you teach them if they can...

Comment: @shoosh Then you can just enforce commit review for every commit. But removing the knob on a door are not getting your user not pass, just to go around and be frustrated by that.